# Only last element prints correctly doubly linked list in C

Tags: c

I want to write a program with a doubly linked list and print it but only last element print prints correctly. In others it prints next in next, current in current, but it also prints current in previous.

```
listw* add(listw* head, int number)
{
    listw* before=head;
    if(head)
        while(before->next)
        {
            before->previous=before;
            before=before->next;
        }

    listw* new=calloc(1, sizeof(listw));
    new->number=number;
    new->next=NULL;
    if (before)
    {
        before->next=new;
        new->previous=before;
    }
    return head ? head : new;
}

int main(){
    listw* head=add(NULL,7);  
    head=add(head,12); 
    head=add(head,18); 
    head=add(head,20);

    for (int i=0; (head->next); i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            printf ("previous: none, now: %d, next: %d\n", head->number, head->next->number);
            head=head->next;
            continue;
        }
        printf("previous: %d, now: %d, next: %d\n", head->previous->number, head->number, head->next->number);
        head=head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: "next in next, current in current" -- what does it mean? please paste the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: please provide code someone can compile...

Comment: Please explain the line that says `before->previous=before`. What does it do? Why do you need it?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that your `add` function is meant to append the new element at the end of the list, and that this loop:

```
if(head)
    while(before->next)
    {
        before->previous=before;
        before=before->next;
    }
```

is meant to find the last element after which you're doing the insertion.

In such a case you have a mistake that you're needlessly modifying `before->previous`, thus making all your `previous` pointers (except the last one) point to their own node. You can simply replace it with:

```
if(before)
    while(before->next)
        before=before->next;
```

Additionally in your printing loop you're not printing the last element. Your condition

```
for (int i=0; (head->next); i++)
```

will terminate the loop when `head` points at the tail -- so `head->next` will be NULL. A rather more idiomatic way to iterate would be:

```
while(head)
{
    if(head->previous)
        printf("previous: %d, ", head->previous->number);
    else
        printf("previous: none, ");

    printf("now: %d, ", head->number);

    if(head->next)
        printf("next: %d\n", head->next->number);
    else
        printf("next: none\n");

    head = head->next;
}
```

You're not very clear on what problem you are facing, so I'm not sure if it solves it for you. However these are the only problems that I can catch in your code.